# cakephp, beginner hello_user test errors

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to catch the information about PHP moreover I've got a project working with CakePHP but it's hard for me to get understand how is CakePHP working.

I created the database with table is `Vkx` and 4 columns is `User_name` , `User_id` , `User_password`, `User_email` I created in model a PHP file : `User.php`

The code:
Model file : User.php

```
<?php

    class User extends AppModel{
         public $name = 'User';
    }
?>
```

Controller File : UsersController

```
class UsersController extends AppController{
     public function hello_user(){
          $user = $this->User->findByuser_id(1);
          $this->set('user',$user);
     }
}
```

Then in Views foder i created Users forder and "Hello_user.ctp" inside:

```
echo "hello , ".$user['User']['user_name']."!";
```

And the Error is:

> Undefined index: User [APP\View\Users\hello_user.ctp, line 8]

Comment: Replace `$user['User']['user_name']` with `$user['user_name']`

Comment: @Phantom that is not a problem check http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#findby

Comment: You can use `debug($user)` to inspect the variable, or install the Debug Kit plug-in

Comment: Table name is `Vkx` ?

Comment: yes ! and the columns's name are in the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct `findByuser_id` to `findByUserId` in this function

```
public function hello_user(){
       $user = $this->User->findByUserId(1);
       $this->set('user',$user);
       }
```

Comment: sorry ! user_id is my collumn in Database ?? If i write findByUserId(1) ? how can it understand ? how can it work ! Thank you so much

Comment: CakePHP inbuilt functionality to understand check http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#findby

Comment: and i already fixed focus what you wrote but it's still be there ! still the same error

Comment: I give one technique hot to debug code. I updated my code for debugging and what you get just tell me. Just copy and paste my code.

Comment: thank you so much ! i got it :D i was fixed by you ! thanks for your help :)

Comment: however i realy ... dizzy and don't understand how the cakephp working >.< !! oh my head :v

Comment: @Xuandao If you got solution then accept my answer so other user will take reference

Comment: i just joined stackoverflow ! how can i accept an answer guy

Comment: ! $user = $this->User->findByUserId(0);
what is "User" in here  ?
is it table's name ?

Comment: User is table name which you mentioned in `MODEL`

Comment: but when i deleted the Model file @@ it's still runing normal ! is model file in this situation have no effect ?

Comment: Cakephp inbulit functionality to load table without declaration of Model class. You will learn cakephp step by step.

Comment: thank you ! so do you have any web or book to learn step by step about cake !